# Full page fade centered loader

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

so i'm relatively new to programing,and i wanted to create a loader that whenever the page loads or refreshes it shows a centered loading animation that greys out and fades the entire page then all goes back to normal when the page fully loads.

i managed to get everything else working except centering the animation and fading/greying the page. idk if i'm missing something really obvious but i've searched everywhere and i didn't quite get what i wanted.

here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>S&B Clothes</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo/icons8-needle-96.png">
</head>

<body id="body">

<!--Navbar-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm sticky-top" id="navbar1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="logo/logo_svg.svg" class="rounded" id="navbar_logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#men_women">
        <div class="container_menu" onclick="menu(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div> 
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="men_women">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="women_index_fn()" id="navbar_men">Women</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <vr class="vr"></vr>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="children_index_fn()" id="navbar_women">Children</button>
          </li>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vr class="vr"></vr>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="men_index_fn()" id="navbar_children">Men</button>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group rounded">
        <input type="search" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" />
        <button type="button" class="btn rounded" id="src_btn">Search</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn" id="user_btn" onmouseover="change_img_user()" onmouseout="change_img_user_2()">
          <img src="Icons/user-white.png" id="user_btn_ico"/>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn" id="favorite_btn" onmouseover="change_img_fav()" onmouseout="change_img_fav_2()">
          <img src="Icons/favorite-white.png" id="favorite_btn_ico"/>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn" id="shop_cart_btn" onmouseover="change_img_cart()" onmouseout="change_img_cart_2()">
          <img src="Icons/shopping-cart-white.png" id="shop_cart_ico"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!--Loader-->

  <div class="preloader" id="ld">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box__inner">
        <div class="box__back-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__right-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__front-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__left-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__front"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box__inner">
        <div class="box__back-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__right-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__front-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__left-flap"></div>
        <div class="box__front"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="line__inner"></div>
    </div>
```

here's the js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  var loader = document.getElementById("ld");
  loader.style.display = "none";
})
```

all the css i've done so far is just loader style and coloring nothing really related to positioning.

i tried putting my loader in a container and centering that but it didn't work out as planned and the navbar didn't get greyed out

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you are asking how to create an overlay and center your loading widget in the middle of the screen. There are a lot of ways your could do this, here is one of them.

```js
function removeOverlay() {
  const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
  overlay.classList.remove('show');
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
 }
```

```css
body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#overlay.show {
  display: block;
}

#overlay-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <header><h2>My Article</h2></header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
    </p>
    </article>
    
    <div id="overlay" class="show">
      <div id="overlay-container">
       <h3>Loading ...</h3>
       <p>Place your loading widget in the overlay-container</p>
       <button onclick="removeOverlay()">Remove Overlay</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: first off i would like to thank you for your help, i just encountered a small problem.
the greyed out overlay doesn't seem to cover the full page so when it loads there's the bottom that's not covered

Comment: @Bilal In the css for #overlay, try this: delete "bottom: 0" and add "height: 100vh".  It is possible that your #overlay div is placed in a container with "position: relative". An element with "position: absolute" is limited to the boundries of its parent if the parent has "position: relative"

Comment: @Bilal I just saw that in my example, the overlay cuts off at the bottom of the screen, but the scroll height is larger, so the bottom of the content is not covered. I'll fix my example.

Comment: @Bilal OK I fixed it. In the css, I added the "overflow: hidden" property to the body tag, which prevents scrolling. Then in the removeOverlay() function, I set the body tag's overflow to "auto".